# Does restarting, reloading or stopping a systemd service have any effect on ExecStartPost?

Tags: systemd

I have a systemd service file where ExecStartPost is used to start a long running process.

Is this process affected in any way by reload being called on the service (assuming ExecReload doesn't do anything related to that process)?

What about when stop is called?

Will calling start on a stopped service invoke the ExecStartPost commands again?

Answer (score 2):

When you call start on the process these commands are executed

- ExecStartPre  Commands that will run before ExecStart.
- ExecStart     Main commands to run when starting the process.
- ExecStartPost Commands that will run after all ExecStart commands have completed.

when you call stop you execute :

- ExecStop  Main commands to run when stopping the process.
- ExecStopPost  Commands that will run after ExecStop has completed.

And when you call reload:

- ExecReload Commands  will run

so to answer your questions

- The process will not be affected when reload is called because ExecReload doesn't do anything related to that process.
- when stop is called this process will be affected if this is specified in ExecStop or ExecStopPost commands
- when start is called ExecStartPost will be invoked again

Comment: The answer could be improved by mentioning or linking to the official docs that the answer is sourced from.